# Acoustic Echo Cancellation (AEC) in embedded software

Tags: embedded, signal-processing, acoustics

I am doing a VoIP project on embedded device. I have built a sample using a 32bits MCU with a low grade audio codec. Now I found that there is echo issue on my device, that is I can hear what I said from the speaker. I have do some research and found that most appliaction use a DSP codec with acoustic echo cancellation feature. However, is it possible that I do the acoustic echo cancellation in the software, using my 32bits MCU?

Can you adive the algorithm, or even source code:P, for doing acoustic echo cancellation? I know sophisticated method is not possible on a MCU, whereas a simple algorithm is also welcomed.

Thank you

[Follow up] : I have tried some AEC code but they can not work well in my MCU, probably it is the limit of the MCU power. I found that my device become non-real-time when implemented these codes (but a VoIP need a real-time respond). At last I implemented a analog hardware solution by adding an AEC chips, because I do not want to write the code again in another DSP chip.

Comment: You can do EC in software and that's pretty much how it's being done nowadays since analogue solutions don't work well (if at all). But it's not an easy feat. First, your hardware must have enough CPU power and memory and have quite linear analogue portion. High nonlinear distortions will usually render EC impossible.

Comment: I also think this is a better question for [dsp.stackexchange.com](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

I had a heck of a time with echo cancellation. I wrote a softphone, and the user can switch their audio input and output devices around to suit their fancy.  I tried the Speex echo cancellation library, and several other open source libs I found online.  None worked well for me.  I tried different speaker/mike configuration and the echo was always there in some form or fashion.

I believe it would be very hard to create AEC code that would work for all possible speaker configurations / room sizes / background noises..etc.  Finally I sat down and wrote my own echo cancellation module for my softphone with this algorithm.

It's somewhat crude, but it has worked well and is reliable.

variable1:
Keep a record of what the average amplitude is of when the person to whom you're talking is speaking. (Don't factor quiet-time)

variable2:
Keep a record of what the average amplitude is on the input (mike), but only when there is voice- again- don't factor quiet time.

As soon as there's audio to play- cut the mike. And assuming the person listening is not talking, turn the mike on 150-300ms after the last audible audio frame comes in to be played.

If the audio from the microphones (that you're dropping during playback) is greater than oh- say (variable2 * 1.5), start sending the audio input frames for a specified duration, resetting that duration every time the input amplitude reaches (variable2 * 1.5).

That way the person talking will know they are being interrupted, and stop to see what the person is saying.  If the person talking doesn't have too noisy of a background, they will probably hear most if not all of the interruption.

Like I said, not the most graceful, but it doesn't use a lot of resources (CPU, memory) and it actually works pretty darn well.  I am very pleased with how mine sounds.

To implement it, I just made a few functions.

On a received audio frame, I call a function I called:

```
void audioin( AEC *ec, short *frame ) {
    unsigned int tas=0; /* Total sum of all audio in frame (absolute value) */
    int i=0;
    for (;i<160;i++)
        tas+=ABS(frame[i]);
    tas/=160; /* 320 byte frames muLaw */
    if (tas>300) { /* I assume this is audiable */
        lockecho(ec);
        ec->lastaudibleframe=GetTickCount64();
        unlockecho(ec);
    }
    return;
}
```

and before sending a frame, I do:

```
#define ECHO_THRESHOLD 300 /* Time to keep suppression alive after last audible frame */
#define ONE_MINUTE 3000 /* 3000 20ms samples */
#define AVG_PERIOD 250 /* 250 20ms samples */
#define ABS(x) (x>0?x:-x)


char removeecho( AEC *ec, short *aecinput ) {
    int tas=0; /* Average absolute amplitude in this signal */
    int i=0;
    unsigned long long *tot=0;
    unsigned int *ctr=0;
    unsigned short *avg=0;
    char suppressframe=0;
    lockecho(ec);
    if (ec->lastaudibleframe+ECHO_THRESHOLD > GetTickCount64() ) {
        /* If we're still within the threshold for echo (speaker state is ON) */
        tot=&ec->t_aiws;
        ctr=&ec->c_aiws;
        avg=&ec->aiws;
    } else {
        /* If we're outside the threshold for echo (speaker state is OFF) */
        tot=&ec->t_aiwos;
        ctr=&ec->c_aiwos;
        avg=&ec->aiwos;
    }
    for (;i<160;i++) {
        tas+=ABS(aecinput[i]);
    }
    tas/=160;
    if (tas>200) {
        (*tot)+=tas;
        (*avg)=(unsigned short)((*tot)/( (*ctr)?(*ctr):1));
        (*ctr)++;
        if ((*ctr)>AVG_PERIOD) {
            (*tot)=(*avg);
            (*ctr)=0;
        }
    }
    if ( (avg==&ec->aiws) ) {
        tas-=ec->aiwos;
        if (tas<0) {
            tas=0;
        }
        if ( ((unsigned short) tas > (ec->aiws*1.5)) && ((unsigned short)tas>=ec->aiwos) && (ec->aiwos!=0) ) {
            suppressframe=0;
        } else {
            suppressframe=1;
        }
    }
    if (suppressframe) { /* Silence frame */
        memset(aecinput, 0, 320);
    }
    unlockecho(ec);
    return suppressframe;
}
```

Which will silence the frame if it needs to.  I keep all my variables, like the timers, and amplitude averages in the AEC struct, which I return from a call to

```
AEC *initecho( void ) {
    AEC *ec=0;
    ec=(AEC *)malloc(sizeof(AEC));
    memset(ec, 0, sizeof(AEC));
    ec->aiws=200; /* Just a default guess as to what the average amplitude would be */
    return ec;
}





typedef struct aec {
    unsigned long long lastaudibleframe; /* time stamp of last audible frame */
    unsigned short aiws; /* Average mike input when speaker is playing */
    unsigned short aiwos; /*Average mike input when speaker ISNT playing */
    unsigned long long t_aiws, t_aiwos; /* Internal running total (sum of PCM) */
    unsigned int c_aiws, c_aiwos; /* Internal counters for number of frames for     averaging */
    unsigned long lockthreadid; /* Thread ID with lock */
    int stlc; /* Same thread lock-count */
} AEC;
```

You can adapt as you need to and play with the idea, but like I said.  It actually sounds pretty dang good.  The only problem I have is if they have a lot of background noise.  But for me, if they pick up their USB handset or are using a headset, they can turn echo cancellation off, and not worry about it...but though PC speakers with a mike...I'm pretty happy with it.

I hope it helps, or gives you something to build on...

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a commercial project that this should be easy. You can integrate a commercial audio cancellation software in your VoIP application.