# how to make expontional smoothing between transitions in signal?

Tags: audio, filter, signal-processing

I'm working on single echo hiding, and need to use exponential smoothing between transitions, so someone can explain to me this method please?

Thank you

Comment: [Echo Canceler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337368/acoustic-echo-cancellation-aec-in-embedded-software)? There's also http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ which might better fit.

Comment: thank you for your answer, this is not exactly what i'm looking. I work on watermarking audio, so i need to use exponential smoothing to obtain more transparency.

Comment: you're welcome :) ... as an alternative to exponential smoothing is an moving average (which i never tried in the Audiocontext).

Comment: what have you tried (example code)? 
Audio Watermark Code at [github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=audio+watermark)

Comment: I have already seen their code but nobody used exponential smoothing. and i haven't idea how can i use it, if you want i send you my code to see it